# jquery getting applied after rendering result in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, angular

I am trying to truncate string based on the number of characters of the string and then append ellipsis if number of chars greater than 21.

I have added a truncate class on the div of html using `jquery`. Everything works fine but when page is getting refreshed, for a second the text is getting display and after that this truncate class is getting applied on it.

Here is my `html` code:

```
<span class="truncate">
    <span *ngIf="result.text1">
        {{result.text1 + "," }}
    </span>
    <span *ngIf="result.text2">
        {{result.text2 + "," }}
    </span>
</span>
```

Here is my jquery code:

```
    setTimeout(() => {
    jQuery('.truncate').each(function (i) {
        if (jQuery(this).text().length > 21) {
            jQuery(this).text(
                jQuery(this)
                    .text()
                    .substr(0, 21) + '...'
            );
        }
    });
```

The result I am getting is something like this if `text1` and `text2` are `text1="My name is xyz"`,

```
text2="Hello Mr.xyz"
```

End result : `"My name is xyz, hello ..."`

I want the `jquery` to be applied applied before the text gets render on page.

Is there any way so that I can delay the rendering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Angular so you can directly use ngClass like this

```
<span class="truncate">
    <div *ngIf="result.text1" [ngClass]="{'text-ellipsis':result.text1.length > 25}">
        {{result.text1 + "," }} {{result.text1.length > 25}}
    </div>
<div *ngIf="result.text2" [ngClass]="{'text-ellipsis':result.text1.length > 25}>
        {{result.text2 + "," }}
    </div>
</span>

.text-ellipsis {
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 120px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

And If you still want to use your code and just solve the rendering issue, then **remove the setTimeout** and place your code inside **ngAfterViewInit** like below. This will update the text after the html page gets loaded.

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
$(".truncate").each(function(i) {
  if ($(this).text().length > 21) {
    $(this).text(
      $(this)
        .text()
        .substr(0, 21) + "..."
    );
  }
});
```

}

Comment: I tried it but again facing same problem where it is displaying for a moment an then ellipsis is getting applied on it.

Comment: Here I just replaced your jquery variable with $

Comment: Here you can take a look at the updated code https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jquery-integration-x1drhw?file=app/app.component.ts

Comment: tried your both of your solutions but not working in my case. Basically I am getting the result from api and we calling that api on each button select. When we get the response we are assigning it to result and after that this variable is getting displayed on dom. After that truncate logic is working. So the time difference between assigning to the variable and applying truncate logic that variable gets displayed on dom. Basically with your jquery solution still I am getting the text displayed for a moment.

Comment: Then directly apply the logic in html like this 
{{(result.text1 && result.text1.length > 21 ? (result.text1.substr(0, 21) + "...") : result.text1) + "," }}
This solution is working for me. This is the stackblitz link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-o5ysmr?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: I already have given a try to this but the problem with approach is ellipsis is getting applied to individual element. In your solution also first ellipsis is applied to text1 and then text2. My requirement here is to applied it in a combine way that is text1 + text2. That is the reason why I have added class="truncate".  Can it be possible with your last approach without jquery?

Comment: So, in your case, will there be only these two text always?

Comment: text1 and text2 is coming as an api response. But in some cases text1 is empty and in some another cases text2 is empty. Both can also be empty. That is the reason why I have added ngIf.

Comment: Updated the stackblitz here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-o5ysmr?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-o5ysmr?file=src/app/app.component.ts
I have added extra conditions based on that. If it works then you can create a pipe also for doing this same thing. That is also a great option for formating response.

Comment: Checked it. And it worked!!! Perfect... Thanks man :)